# Align iFrame videos together

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to align videos together.

For example Episode 6 should be next to Episode 1, Episode 7 next to Episode 2 etc.

However I'm having trouble doing so. I know I can do  bottom:1700px and left: 640px, but it isn't perfectly aligned.

Can someone help me?

IMAGE:
https://gyazo.com/57127cbb9aa733c8bbaf104f2b8df388

Code:

```
<div class="single_right">
                            <h3>Highway Patrol Season 1 </h3>
                            <p class="m_10">Season 1 all episodes!</p>



                            <div class="btn_form">
                               <form>

                                <a>
                            <div>
                            <h3>
                                <text> Episode 1 </text><br>

                                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//sendvid.com/embed/vas7m0j8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 


                               <text> Episode 2 </text>

                               <iframe width="560" height="315"  src="//sendvid.com/embed/u2gappdn" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                               <br>

                               <text> Episode 3 </text>
                               <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//sendvid.com/embed/zig4qs7q" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                               <text> Episode 4 </text>
                               <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//sendvid.com/embed/g09xk3f8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                               <text> Episode 5 </text>
                               <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//sendvid.com/embed/h7z80p3m" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


                                 <text> Episode 6</text>

                                 <iframe width="560" height="315"  src="//sendvid.com/embed/9fd0zbfk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                                 <text> Episode 7</text>

                                 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//sendvid.com/embed/s33v2ndt" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                                 <text> Episode 8 </text>

                                 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//sendvid.com/embed/w6b54hjx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                                 </h3>


                              </form>
                            </div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.single_image{
    width:36.5%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2.6%;
}
.single_right{
    width: 60.5%;
    float: left;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: you want 2 videos in one row??

Comment: you have too many wrong nested tags.

Comment: you need to improve your code..like a tag never ends, form closing before div. And for floating out you need to put video1-5 and video 6-8 in different div and then apply *float:left* to both the divs.